# Android TV app rejected, with no further details provided / tickets being ignored

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, android-tv

My app got rejected multiple times from google play with reason:

> Depends on menu Your app depends on having a “Start,” “Select,” or
> “Menu” button to reach the menu. Android TV controllers do not support
> a “Select,” “Start,” or “Menu” button. Please refer to our Gamepad
> Button Presses documentation for details:
> http://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input.html#buttonProcess

My application was tested both on multiple tv controllers and gamepads and it is working fine. All appeal tickets are being ignored for several weeks.

Comment: unfortunately, there's quite literally nothing we can do for you here

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic. You might want to focus on what it is that they might be seeing in your app that they do not like.

Comment: My best guess is that you have UI that indicates the user can/should press the start/select/menu button. If your app says something like "press the menu button to open the menu," it's going to get rejected even if you can get to the menu another way because the reference remote does not include a menu button, so those directions are confusing to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting google they told me you can reply to the email they sent you about the appeal and ask for more info and screenshots. After I replied to that email I got the answer in 1 hour with a screenshot.
In my case problem were store listing images, there were some buttons that were not supported by android tv (red, green, blue, yellow buttons). I used the same pictures as for Samsung and Lg and totally forgot to remove these buttons from images.
I have removed those buttons from images and submitted the app again. After an hour my app was approved for android tv.

I found out you can contact google at this link just scroll at the bottom where it says contact us and you can just start live chat with them it's that easy lol.

Comment: I have the same issues, but when I asked for details they replied "As much as I'd like to help, I’m not able to provide any more detail or a better answer to your question.". Just: "your app (version code 17 and 18)  crashes and error occurs." but I cannot reproduce it and there are no logs on firebase..